# Libvirt shared storage pool

Tags: kvm-virtualization, storage, libvirt, virsh, gfs2

I have what I hope is a quick question.  I'm running:

- CENTOS 9
- KVM/QEMU
- Pacemaker, DLM, lvmlockd, fence_scsi

I have a simple two node KVM cluster where I've set up a LVM logical volume on a attached iSCSI LUN formatted with GFS2.  I've been following RH's "[Configuring and managing high availability clusters guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/pdf/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/red_hat_enterprise_linux-9-configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters-en-us.pdf)".

From a pacemaker, LVM locking, fencing, shared filesystem standpoint, things look good:

```
[root@lab-kvm-01 ~]# pcs status --full
Cluster name: kvm_cluster
Cluster Summary:
  * Stack: corosync (Pacemaker is running)
  * Current DC: lab-kvm-01.domain.local (1) (version 2.1.6-10.1.el9-6fdc9deea29) - partition with quorum
  * Last updated: Wed Dec  6 15:11:19 2023 on lab-kvm-01.domain.local
  * Last change:  Wed Dec  6 12:10:47 2023 by root via cibadmin on lab-kvm-02.domain.local
  * 2 nodes configured
  * 7 resource instances configured

Node List:
  * Node lab-kvm-01.domain.local (1): online, feature set 3.17.4
  * Node lab-kvm-02.domain.local (2): online, feature set 3.17.4

Full List of Resources:
  * Clone Set: locking-clone [locking]:
     * Resource Group: locking:0:
      * dlm     (ocf:pacemaker:controld):        Started lab-kvm-01.domain.local
      * lvmlockd        (ocf:heartbeat:lvmlockd):        Started lab-kvm-01.domain.local
    * Resource Group: locking:1:
      * dlm     (ocf:pacemaker:controld):        Started lab-kvm-02.domain.local
      * lvmlockd        (ocf:heartbeat:lvmlockd):        Started lab-kvm-02.domain.local
  * scsi-shooter        (stonith:fence_scsi):    Started lab-kvm-01.domain.local
  * Clone Set: shared_vg-clone [shared_vg]:
    * Resource Group: shared_vg:0:
      * shared_lv       (ocf:heartbeat:LVM-activate):    Started lab-kvm-01.domain.local
    * Resource Group: shared_vg:1:
     * shared_lv       (ocf:heartbeat:LVM-activate):    Started lab-kvm-02.domain.local

Migration Summary:

Fencing History:
  * unfencing of lab-kvm-02.domain.local successful: delegate=lab-kvm-02.domain.local, client=pacemaker-controld.1642, origin=lab-kvm-01.domain.local, completed='2023-12-06 14:42:24.976410 -05:00'
  * unfencing of lab-kvm-01.domain.local successful: delegate=lab-kvm-01.domain.local, client=pacemaker-controld.1642, origin=lab-kvm-01.domain.local, completed='2023-12-06 14:26:16.176473 -05:00'

Tickets:

PCSD Status:
  lab-kvm-01.domain.local: Online
  lab-kvm-02.domain.local: Online

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

What I had hoped to do at this point was add this shared storage as a libvirt storage pool.  However, setting up a shared storage pool seems kinda vague in the libvirt documentation.  Currently what I run into, after defining the storage pool, is a locking error when starting the pool:

```
[root@lab-kvm-01 ~]# virsh pool-define-as shared_pool logical --source-name vg_gfs2 --target /dev/vg_gfs2/
Pool shared_pool defined

[root@lab-kvm-01 ~]# virsh pool-start shared_pool
error: Failed to start pool shared_pool
error: internal error: Child process (/usr/sbin/vgchange -aly vg_gfs2) unexpected exit status 5:   LV locked by other host: vg_gfs2/lv_gfs2
  Failed to lock logical volume vg_gfs2/lv_gfs2.
```

So taking a step back at this point, I have a few questions:

1. How exactly do you go about setting up a shared storage pool for a KVM / QEMU cluster? Obviously I want a shared filesystem like GFS2.  It'd be nice to have pacemaker manage DLM, lvmlocking, etc.
2. In reading through man pages, libvirt documentation, setting up a logical storage pool seems to be done at the volume group.  And I guess libvirt is supposed to recognize existing filesystems? However it looks like libvirt wants to have some control over activating and managing the volume group.  I had hoped I could simply provide the storage to libvirt and it'd be happy.
3. There is also the pool-build option that mentions creating a fileystem.  But how would it know that I want a shared filesystem and to manage locking accordingly?

Hopefully the above makes sense.  All I want is a shared storage pool for my VMs.  I'm just confused on how to set this up using libvirt.

Comment: I was able to use vgchange --lockstop, vgchange --lockstart to resolve the issue.